# Multiply columns of different dataframes having the same name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, data-transform

I have two dataframes which have different no of rows and columns but have few columns with same names. I want to create a dataframe which has the common columns and the columns with same name have their values multiplied. ***I want it in a way where I can automte that process without having to bother about the dataframe sizes.***

First dataframe

```
Product   1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
   1          1          10          1          
   2          2          20          1           
   3          3          30          10            
   4          2          10          5            
   5          4           5          10
```

This is the second dataframe

```
Product    Skill     1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
   1         W2         1            1          10          
   2         W45        20           1           0           
   3         W0         40           5           0            
   4         W1         50           5           1            
   5         W2         2            2           1
```

The resultant dataframe should be of the form where the values of columns with matching names are multiplied.

```
Product    Skill     1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
   1         W2         1           10          10          
   2         W45        40          20           0           
   3         W0         120         150          0            
   4         W1         100         50           5            
   5         W2         8           10          10
```

Comment: Can you post both data.frames in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`. And the same for `df2`.

Comment: I'm afraid the output of head() is too wide.

Comment: Can't you subset, selecting some columns only? A mix of common and not common  names?

Comment: Both dataframes have combined column count of 1000. So no.

Comment: Assuming the data as posted have the columns in order, it would be `df1[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]` and `df2[c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]`. This is surely possible.

Comment: If columns are in the same order, and same number of rows and columns, drop the leading columns and multiply: `df1[, -1] * df2[, -c(1:2)]`

Comment: If you have have different number of rows in both the dataframe how will you multiply them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that works with the posted data. I believe it is a general purpose function.

```
multCols <- function(x, y, id = "Product"){
  xnum <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  ynum <- sapply(y, is.numeric)
  xnames <- names(x)[xnum]
  ynames <- names(y)[ynum]
  xynames <- intersect(xnames, ynames)
  xyid <- intersect(x[[id]], y[[id]])
  i <- match(xyid, x[[id]])
  j <- match(xyid, y[[id]])
  x[i, xynames] * y[j, xynames]
}

multCols(df1, df2)
#  Product 1/1/2020 1/1/2019 1/1/2018
#1       1        1       10       10
#2       4       40       20        0
#3       9      120      150        0
#4      16      100       50        5
#5      25        8       10       10
```